# coffeescript how to unpack like "tuples" in python

Tags: coffeescript

I'm new to coffeescript.  Is there a way to take these three lines setting the rotation and accomplish the same thing, like you would do in python by unpacking a tuple?

```
@cosines = [0,1,0]
@branch.rotation.x = Math.asin(@cosines.x)
@branch.rotation.y = Math.asin(@cosines.y)
@branch.rotation.z = Math.asin(@cosines.z)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the best code I could come up with.

```
@cosines = [0,1,0]
rot = @branch.rotation
[rot.x, rot.y, rot.z] = [Math.asin(c) for c in @cosines]
```

The <strike>unpacking</strike> [destructuring](http://coffeescript.org/#destructuring) is the same as in Python, but with square brackets.